# jquery issue on IE with selectors

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser, selector

I am migrating a legacy javascript function to jquery

here is the function

```
function doSomething(elId, imId) {
      //  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#' + elId).toggle();
        alert('id is: ' + $('#' + elId).attr('id'));
        //});
}
```

the function works fine on Firefox but IE says undefined on alert box... any idea what am i missing?

Comment: Maybe you are using `elId` with `-` (hyphen)?

Comment: no id value will be something like divID1234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there were some extra spaces in between attributes of html tag such as id="asdf"                  href="something". That was causing the issue on IE.. its resolved..

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling doSomething from within a document ready?

Comment: You should write answers to "answers" and questions to "comments".

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Still getting used to the ui.